# How to filter by field values in REST

Tags: rest, url

I've implemented REST service so that clients can request specific fields they are interested in to minimize traffic:

```
domain.com/rest/articles?fields=tag&fields=translation
```

Now I want to also filter by those fields, for example, I want server to return only articles which match `tag` with `id` 3. What is the common approach to constructing URLs to allow that?

This approach seems weird:

```
domain.com/rest/articles?fields=tag=3&fields=translation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
domain.com/rest/articles?fields=tag,translation&tag=3
```

Comment: Any link to standard or common practice to validate that approach?

Comment: Some guys I used to work with who know alot more than me taught me this approach

Comment: Do you know if this approach is CGI spec compliant?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cgi specs, sorry